# Is there any property on SQL Server similar to Oracle's auto limit?

Tags: sql-server, limit

There are a lot of records on my table. Sometimes I can forget using top keyword while querying so after that it can be very annoying to be waiting for so long. Oracle brings top 500 records if you don't use limit keyword. Is there any property or a secret thing (wow! ) on sql similar to Oracle's auto limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rowcount`:

```
SET rowcount 500
```

---

> SET ROWCOUNT overrides the SELECT statement TOP keyword if the
>   rowcount is the smaller value.
>
> SET ROWCOUNT is ignored in INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements when
>   an explicit TOP expression is used in the same statement. This
>   includes statements in which INSERT is followed by a SELECT clause.
>
> The setting of SET ROWCOUNT is set at execute or run time and not at
>   parse time.

---

To set this option off so that all rows are returned, specify `SET ROWCOUNT 0`.

For more info, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)!

Comment: "sometimes I can forget using top keyword..."

Comment: `ROWNUM` might be the way to go!

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't read the question carefully. First: The OP is aware of the TOP keyword. He just sometimes forget it, so he is looking for a way(or configuration setting) that automatically sets a limit on queries. Second: Your ROWNUM is a column in Oracle, but this Question is SQL-Server related only.

Comment: Ok, the ROWCOUNT can be helpful +1, but i'm yet not convinced why it's easier to remember instead of TOP ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter top is only for one `select`, `rowcount` is always for all

Comment: :) thanks but not exactly what I'm looking for. What If I forget to put that? same story again. I really dont understand how sql does not include a specification like this.

Comment: @MustafaGüven is you put that one time, it will be for every time, to disable you need to `SET ROWCOUNT 0`.

Comment: @aF. I see what you did there :) thanks bro. I thought I need to put it on top for every query. This was totally what I searched for. thanks again.

Comment: @MustafaGüven - You can set a default up in `SSMS -> Tools -> Query Options`. I wouldn't bother though. It also affects data modification statements and if you are prone to forgetting `TOP` then what's to say you won't forget to disable it before running an update?